# How to address elements of multidimensional array with variables?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vector

```
import numpy as np
cube = np.zeros((2,2,2,2,2,2,2)) # Make 7 dim hypercube
vector=[1,0,1,1,0,1,1]
cube[vector[0],vector[1],vector[2],vector[3],vector[4],vector[5],vector[6]] # access the field [1,0,1,1,0,1,1]
```

I have to work with some high dimensional arrays and I would like to access their fields through variables.
The above code shows a very bad solution and I am sure that there is a more efficient one, something similar to `cube[vector]` or `cube[vector[i] for i in range(len(vector))]` but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy indexes are just tuples, so you can:

```
cube[tuple(vector)]
```